# Are they both correct? “He’s the tallest of the three” and “He’s the tallest among the three”

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, descriptive-grammar

Are both of these correct?

> He’s the tallest of the three.
>
> He’s the tallest among the three.

My teacher said that I shouldn’t use “among” here. Is that related to the number of items in the comparison?

So what about “He’s the tallest of the four” and “He’s the tallest among the four”?

Comment: I wouldn’t go so far as to say that *among* is, but of the two, *of* is far and away more common.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the number of things being compared.